# How to make some parts of a regex pattern conditional?

Tags: regex

I checked this forum for a answer to my problem, but couldnt find. Experts please help.

I have a problem to validate a string say first name. I am given a set of rules which the string needs to honor and the same needs to be confirmed with regex. I wrote a pattern. Except one rule my pattern honors everything else. I am listing my regex pattern below

```
([A-Za-z]+[-'!` ]?)*
```

I am checking for a string say first or last name which needs to start with a alphabet and can have any one of (- or ! or ' or ` or spaces ) these 5 characters ONE AND ONLY IF there is a second word. If a name has 2 words with a space in between then its ok. some examples

```
List of Valid Names
TIMOTHY
JONATHON
PATRICK
B`ELLA
SUZY JANE - Only one space allowed
SUZY-JANE

List of Invalid Ones
T~ELLA - Because this ~ is not part of regex
SUZY - JANE - No space allowed between hyphens
SUZY  JANE - 2 spaces betweeb words not allowed
GRACO&LAME - & is not allowed
```

My regex passes all these above conditions But fails when the name ends in any one of the special character. For example, if I give JOHN- OR JOHN' OR JOHN! OR JOHN` OR JOHN (with s spaces at the end) these are not valid but my regex isnt able to handle it

Can some one tell me how to write a conditional regex? Like one and only if there is a second word then the regex pattern must allow the entry of these special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[A-Za-z]+(?:[-'!` ]?[A-Za-z]+)?
```

You can check it online here: [regexr](http://regexr.com?2td13)

The second part

```
(?:[-'!` ]?[A-Za-z]+)?
```

is a non capturing group, this group is because of the `?` at the end optional.

Answer (score 1):

Let Name be the regex for the simple name, Special the set of special characters (including the space). Then your final regex looks like

```
Name(SpecialName)?
```

Comment: @Ingo-I am sorry I dont clearly understand how to interpret your answer.

Comment: Name=[A-Z]+  Special=[!- ]   Regex=[A-Z]+([!- ][A-Z]+)?

Comment: @Ingo - Trying your solution now

Comment: If '-' is a special character, it must be the first one in the character class. That is why I gave a symbolic answer, I expected you insert your previous values.

Comment: @Ingo - Here is the thing - [A-Za-z]+([!-'` ]?[A-Za-z]*)? Suzy-Jane fails for this one

Comment: remove the ? after the special character class and the * after the second [A-Z...] class must be a + AND you have still '-' not on the 1str position in the special class

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is repeat the text definition to have to exist 1 or more times AFTER the punctuation.  This will work, but every name needs to be at least 2 characters (which seems reasonable..)

[A-Za-z]+[-'!` ]?[A-Za-z]+

Comment: this matches the empty string as well as "a-za-za-z"

Comment: Oops, I copy and pasted his original and left in the ()*.  Took out, and now it should work.

Comment: I am validating first and last name separately. your solution is perfect if i validate first and last name as one string. In my case first name itself can have more than one string. So its isnt mandatory that i can expect a second string.

Comment: This works on a single string.. it just needs at least two characters.  "De" would validate as true.