# In python, how to use regex to conditionally pattern match

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

I am trying to parse the following string with python's regex library:

```
recipe_a = 'run_list[sm_collectd::default@1.0.0]'
```

Using http://pythex.org/, I am trying out the following regexes:

```
\[(.*)::(.*)@(.*)\]
```

Which yields:

```
Match 1
    1.  sm_collectd
    2.  default
    3.  1.0.0
```

**Here is the problem:**

recipe_a can be pattern matched with this regex, however, it fails when the **@version** is no longer specified in the string. The following example will fail to match the pattern:

```
recipe_b = 'run_list[sm_collectd::default]'
```

`\\[(.\*)::(.\*)@(.\*)\\]` fails in this case because @ was never matched. have python logic that trys `\\[(.\*)::(.\*)@(.\*)\\]` and tries the latter regex `\\[(.\*)::(.\*)\\]`. But that would be silly. It would be nice if I could accomplish this in one regex pattern.

I have tried solving this with a conditional regex statement. The general syntax I have tried is as follows:

```
(?(?=regex)then|else)
```

the first ? is lookahead assertion: matches without consuming. So we could have a conditional match on the `@` symbol.

if the `@` is matched then do `\\[(.\*)::(.\*)@(.\*)\\]`, else do `\\[(.\*)::(.\*)\\]`.

**PROGRAMATIC SOLUTION**

```
kitchen_recipe = 'recipe[my_cookbook::default@0.1.0]'

recipe = kitchen_recipe.strip('recipe[').strip(']')
if '@' in recipe:
    cookbook, recipe, cookbook_version = tuple(re.split('::|@', recipe))
else:
    cookbook, recipe = tuple(re.split('::', recipe))
    cookbook_version = None   # no version specified
```

**REGEX SOLUTION**

```
kitchen_recipe = 'recipe[my_cookbook::default@0.1.0]'

run_list_pattern = '\[(.*)::([^@]*)@?([0-9.]*)\]'
cookbook, recipe, cookbook_version = re.search(test_list_pattern,
                                               kitchen_recipe).groups()
```

Comment: > It would be nice if I could accomplish this in one regex pattern.

In my experience I would way rather have explicit code than confusing regex when reading it later.

Comment: perhaps your are correct, but a regex solution would be nice in this case.

Comment: Personally I would use two functions then test for @ to decide which one to call... `if '@' in recipe then regex_1(recipe): else regex_2(recipe)` but the first suggested link might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444424/how-to-make-some-parts-of-a-regex-pattern-conditional?rq=1

Comment: Please don't post your solution in the question post, you can answer your own question with the solution and state that you are looking for a better solution but posting the answer in the question makes it less likely future viewers will even see the posted answers.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of small changes should work for your purposes; try `\[(.*)::([^@]*)(?:@(.*))?\]`

`run_list[sm_collectd::default]` yields

1. `sm_collectd`
2. `default`
3. None

`run_list[sm_collectd::default@1.0.0]` yields

1. `sm_collectd`
2. `default`
3. `1.0.0`

#### Explanation:

I changed the final `@(.*)` into `(?:@(.*))?`. The additional `(?:)` is a *non-capturing* group, and the following `?` means "match 0 or 1 times".

I also changed the first `(.*)` into `([^@]*)`, which means match anything but an `@` as many times as possible, so it won't treat all of `default@1.0.0` as the chef recipe name.

---

Edit: As @gregory points out, you can avoid the non-capturing group. You can use `\[(.*)::([^@]*)@?(.*)\]`.

If you'd like to limit the version number to only digits and `.`s: `\[(.*)::([^@]*)@?([0-9.]*)\]`.

Comment: this is great. I like your suggestion.

Comment: And if you want to avoid the non-capturing group: (\[[^:]*)::([^\@]+)@*([0-9.]+)*

Comment: @gregory Good point! Edited into the answer, with the minor change of allowing max 1 `@` (if limiting version number to digits only, which the OP doesn't)